# Nginx/PHP-CGI - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, nginx

I appear to be having an issue with my website when I browse around (just clicking links here and there), and my system would return a random 502 Bad Gateway error. I can hit the refresh button and it would appear to work fine.

Error Message:

```
2012/08/16 11:17:54 [error] 26777#0: *1049 recv() failed 
    (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, 
    client: 66.162.194.10, server: SITE, 
    request: "GET /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dashboard-widgets&widget=dashboard_secondary HTTP/1.1", 
    upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php.socket:", host: "SITE", referrer: "SITE/wp-admin/index.php"

2012/08/16 11:17:54 [error] 26777#0: *1049 connect() failed 
    (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, 
    client: 66.162.194.10, server: SITE, 
    request: "GET /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dashboard-widgets&widget=dashboard_secondary HTTP/1.1", 
    upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dashboard-widgets&widget=dashboard_secondary", 
    host: "SITE", referrer: "http://SITE/wp-admin/index.php"

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;
```

Comment: Bummer. Do you have a question, though?

Comment: Upstream is usually php-fpm. How did you configure php-fpm (max connections, ports)? And what does your /etc/nginx/conf.d/yourwebsite.conf looks like (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yourwebsite.conf in Debian like distros)

Comment: rdlowrey: How do I fix the issue so I do not recieve the 502 Bad Gateway error?

Comment: John: 
apparently I left the default settings for FPM

Website Config: http://pastebin.com/wXwAUkiJ